# Remove question mark from URL other than PHP . ID

Tags: php

I have a website, developed by some developer, the website is with me now.. The issue is the website have a "?" with in the URL..

eg.

http://www.imljeans.com/?/collection/search_by/women/2

Is there a way to remove "?" from this url... if I remove this "?" from the website, the website stops working. all pages on the website have the same issue.

Is there a way to sort this...

Comment: The developer may be tearing apart the url after ?, seems it would have been a clever way to point all urls to the index.php.

Comment: It is possible by doing URL rewriting http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Are you using apache as web server?

Answer (score 1):

You have to take advantage of url rewrite with .htacess

Basically a rule like

```
RewriteRule ^?/(.*)$ /$1
```

Comment: asuming he's using apache